# How can I split a string into an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, input, split

I need to capture an equation (e.g. 2x^2-1x) I have this piece of code to capture it

```
string eq;
cin>>eq;
```

In order to solve it I need to split every character of the previous string into an array and then proceed solve it with a loop. I think I know how to do the looping part but how can I split it into an array? or is there an easier method to do this?

Comment: You need a tokenizer. Im afraid you have to implement it.

Comment: You need a tokenizer. Im afraid you have to implement it.

Comment: is your equation always of the form `ax^2+bx+c` and you need to parse the values for `a`,`b`, and `c`?

Comment: There is no "easier method" to do anything in C++. C++ is arguably the most complex contemporary general purpose programming language. You will need to learn how to examine the contents of a `std::string`, how to extract various parts of the string, and how to put the pieces into an array or a vector. For more information,see your C++ book.

Comment: @StephanLechner you're on to something. It's probably one of the many polynomial exercises. (Ironically I had already voted to close as "too broad" long before I added my way-too-generic answer)

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually trying to split a string into an array. An array will buy you nothing. You want an expression tree. Or at least a recursive descent parse that evaluates on the fly. That'll be easier but less efficient.

There must be numerous questions/answers on recursive descent expression parsers on StackOverflow. Use the search box to get ideas.

### DEMO

In the interest of complete overkill, here's a sample of a formula evaluation function with dynamic (single-letter) variables, and some test-cases.

It uses C++14 and Boost Spirit X3. Here the "recursive descent" parser is generated from [PEG rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) instead of being handwritten.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0b9e522c8eb0122)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <map>

using VarMap = std::map<char, double>;

namespace formula {
    namespace detail {
        using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

        #define BIN(f)    ([](auto &ctx) { _val(ctx) = f(_val(ctx), _attr(ctx)); })
        #define BINOP(op) BIN(([](auto a, auto b) { return a op b; }))
        #define IDENT     ([](auto &ctx) { _val(ctx) = _attr(ctx); })

        static VarMap var_map;
        auto lookup = [](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = var_map.at(_attr(ctx)); };

        rule<struct f_, double> factor {"factor"};
        rule<struct t_, double> term   {"term"};
        rule<struct x_, double> expo   {"expo"};

        auto var     = rule<struct _v, double> {"var"} 
                     = alpha [lookup];
        auto literal = !lit('-') >> double_;
        auto simple  = rule<struct _l, double> {"simple"}
                     = ('(' >> term >> ')') | var | literal;

        auto expo_def 
            = simple [IDENT] >> *('^' >> expo)[BIN(pow)];

        auto factor_def = expo [IDENT] >> *(
                    '*' >> factor [BINOP(*)]
                  | '/' >> factor [BINOP(/)]
                  | factor        [BINOP(*)]
              );

        auto term_def = factor [IDENT] >> *(
                    '+' >> term [BINOP(+)]
                  | '-' >> term [BINOP(-)]
              );

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expo, factor, term)

        auto expr = skip(space) [eps > term > eoi];
    }

    struct evaluation_error : std::runtime_error {
        evaluation_error(std::string const& msg) : std::runtime_error(msg) {}
    };

    double eval(std::string const& formula, VarMap vars) {
        using namespace std::string_literals;
        detail::var_map = vars;

        double value;
        try {
            bool ok = parse(begin(formula), end(formula), detail::expr, value);
            assert(ok);
            return value;
        } catch(boost::spirit::x3::expectation_failure<std::string::const_iterator> const& e) {
            throw evaluation_error("syntax: expect " + e.which() + " at '" + std::string(e.where(), formula.end()) + "'");
        } catch(std::out_of_range const& e) {
            throw evaluation_error("variable undefined");
        } catch(std::exception const& e) {
            throw evaluation_error("eval: "s + e.what());
        }

    }
}

int main() {
    for (auto formula : { "", "0", "2", "x", "2x",
            "x^2",
            "2x^2",
            "2x^2-1x",
            "2x^2-sin x",
            "x^(1/2)",
            "(x^(1/2))^2",
            }) 
    try {
        std::cout << "Function f(x) -> " << formula << "\n";
        for (double x = 0; x < 10; x += 1)
            std::cout << " - f(" << x << ") -> " << formula::eval(formula, {{'x', x}}) << "\n";
    } catch(formula::evaluation_error const& e) {
        std::cout << "Oops: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Function f(x) -> 
 - f(0) -> Oops: syntax: expect term at ''
Function f(x) -> 0
 - f(0) -> 0
 - f(1) -> 0
 - f(2) -> 0
 - f(3) -> 0
 - f(4) -> 0
 - f(5) -> 0
 - f(6) -> 0
 - f(7) -> 0
 - f(8) -> 0
 - f(9) -> 0
Function f(x) -> 2
 - f(0) -> 2
 - f(1) -> 2
 - f(2) -> 2
 - f(3) -> 2
 - f(4) -> 2
 - f(5) -> 2
 - f(6) -> 2
 - f(7) -> 2
 - f(8) -> 2
 - f(9) -> 2
Function f(x) -> x
 - f(0) -> 0
 - f(1) -> 1
 - f(2) -> 2
 - f(3) -> 3
 - f(4) -> 4
 - f(5) -> 5
 - f(6) -> 6
 - f(7) -> 7
 - f(8) -> 8
 - f(9) -> 9
Function f(x) -> 2x
 - f(0) -> 0
 - f(1) -> 2
 - f(2) -> 4
 - f(3) -> 6
 - f(4) -> 8
 - f(5) -> 10
 - f(6) -> 12
 - f(7) -> 14
 - f(8) -> 16
 - f(9) -> 18
Function f(x) -> x^2
 - f(0) -> 0
 - f(1) -> 1
 - f(2) -> 4
 - f(3) -> 9
 - f(4) -> 16
 - f(5) -> 25
 - f(6) -> 36
 - f(7) -> 49
 - f(8) -> 64
 - f(9) -> 81
Function f(x) -> 2x^2
 - f(0) -> 0
 - f(1) -> 2
 - f(2) -> 8
 - f(3) -> 18
 - f(4) -> 32
 - f(5) -> 50
 - f(6) -> 72
 - f(7) -> 98
 - f(8) -> 128
 - f(9) -> 162
Function f(x) -> 2x^2-1x
 - f(0) -> 0
 - f(1) -> 1
 - f(2) -> 6
 - f(3) -> 15
 - f(4) -> 28
 - f(5) -> 45
 - f(6) -> 66
 - f(7) -> 91
 - f(8) -> 120
 - f(9) -> 153
Function f(x) -> 2x^2-sin x
 - f(0) -> Oops: variable undefined
Function f(x) -> x^(1/2)
 - f(0) -> 0
 - f(1) -> 1
 - f(2) -> 1.41421
 - f(3) -> 1.73205
 - f(4) -> 2
 - f(5) -> 2.23607
 - f(6) -> 2.44949
 - f(7) -> 2.64575
 - f(8) -> 2.82843
 - f(9) -> 3
Function f(x) -> (x^(1/2))^2
 - f(0) -> 0
 - f(1) -> 1
 - f(2) -> 2
 - f(3) -> 3
 - f(4) -> 4
 - f(5) -> 5
 - f(6) -> 6
 - f(7) -> 7
 - f(8) -> 8
 - f(9) -> 9
```

Comment: Because I'm ---bored--- crazy and like a challenge, I made a demonstration: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bde0b969f65a036a)

Comment: Improved/simplified version: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e56ded161cf708c1). Hilariously, debug output reduced from 2.3m to 8k lines, less than 4‰ :) Same output of course

Answer (score 3):

An `std::string` is already a container, you can loop over it:

```
std::string eq = "2x^2-1x";
for (char c : eq)
{
  // use c
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about doing is a lexer. There is one in Linux (Microsoft uses it too now) called `lex` or `flex` (it's really from GNU). There is a C++ extension for it. That will take care of the parsing.

From what I can see in your example:

```
[0-9]+      number
[a-z]       letter
.           operator
```

Once you have a lexer, you want a compiler. That's where `yacc` comes in. Again, there is one with a C++ extension and it is called Bison (from GNU).

`yacc` allows you to write your parsing nearly however complex it can become. There are limits in LALR parsers — *Look Ahead Left-to-right Rightmost (derivation)*, although Bison gives you support for GLR too — *Generalized Left-to-right Rightmost (derivation)*.

Why is `yacc` much easier to use than writing your own C/C++ code? Because it will take priority in account without you having to do any work. When you write `a + b * c` you know that you first need to compute `b * c` then you add `a` to that product. It's not as easy if you write your own code (it's not that hard either if you know how to do it.)

`yacc` has rules which look a bit like this (without the necessary code):

```
start: expr

expr: expr '+' expr
    | expr '-' expr
    | expr '*' expr
    | expr '/' expr
    | expr '^' expr
    | '+' expr
    | '-' expr
    | '(' expr ')'
```

Somewhere you'll have to define the priority of each operator. `'+'` and `'-`' are lowest here, then `'*'` and `'/'`, and then `'^'`. (Also the `'^'` has another *problem*, it is a "compute the right hand side first", so `3^2^4` is equivalent to `3^(2^4)` but I won't go in those details.)

Some additional info and an actual real example of an entire such project:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison

Comment: Solid post. I think the OP is getting a bit more than was deserved here, but it's quality information. I love it. I'm learning still :)

Answer (score 1):

A `std::string` provides access to its contents in the form of an array:

```
const string::size_type n=eq.length();
for(string::size_type i=0; i<n; ++i)
  do_something(eq[i]);
// or see erenon's range-for example
```

However, be warned that [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages) (analyzing the string to understand the equation) gets very complicated very quickly; the array access is by far the easy part.